# CSS - dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm new with CSS and testing some stuff. I created a dropdown menu but this doesn't work correctly.
Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href = "üben_css.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title> xx</title>
</head>

<body>  


<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li> Home       </li>
        <li> xx
            <ul>
                <li> Hc </li>
                <li> Scc    </li>
            </ul>
        <li>Zubehör     </li>
        <li> Service    </li>
        <li> Forum </li>

    </ul>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

CSS code:

```
  body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#nav{
background-color:silver;
position:relative;
}

#nav ul li{

display:inline;
}

#nav ul ul{
display:none;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
}

#nav ul ul li{
display:block;
}
```

The problem is that the nav bar is displayed inline but when I hover over my "xx" element the rest of my nav bar appear under my dropdown list. How can I fix this?

http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/20140921004u0kxad3i2r.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
#nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Compared to just `inline`. If it was just `inline` the `absolute` positioning below would cause multiple dropdowns to all appear in the same place according to the `#nav` div.

```
#nav ul li:hover ul{
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
}
```

This still doesn't look very good but it's functional. Checkout at [tutsplus](http://tutsplus.com/) for some good tutorials.

At the same time, I'm sure you could solve this much more efficiently with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Remove these lines from your css:

```
#nav ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
}
```